# Extract URL Query Value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to extract a query value `q=` from a URL using Excel. The main challenge I'm facing is that the query value isn't always in the same position. I can have multiple parameters before or after the query value. All I know is that I need to start from the `&q=` position, and end at the next `&` symbol, or the end of line if no other `&` follows.

For example: in the URL below, I'm looking to extract the query value of: `This_Is_My_Query_value`

```
http://www.example.com/somepage?param1=one&param2=two&param3=three`&q=This_Is_My_Query_value`&A=Z&B=y&C=ahUKEwjS09bhyPD1AhVihOAKHTQyBeEQwL
```

Query string splitter:

- `'param1':` one
- `'param2':` two
- `'param3':` three
- `'q':` **This_Is_My_Query_value**
- `'A':` Z
- `'B':` y
- `'C':` ahUKEwjS09bhyPD1AhVihOAKHTQyBeEQwL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two stages:

```
A1      (Your URL)
        http://www.example.com/somepage?param1=one&param2=two&param3=three&q=This_Is_My_Query_value&A=Z&B=y&C=ahUKEwjS09bhyPD1AhVihOAKHTQyBeEQwL

B1      =MID(@A:A,FIND("q=",@A:A)+2,999)
        This_Is_My_Query_value&A=Z&B=y&C=ahUKEwjS09bhyPD1AhVihOAKHTQyBeEQwL

C1      =LEFT(@B:B,IFERROR(FIND("&",@B:B)-1,999))
        This_Is_My_Query_value
```

Or you can do it in a single formula:

```
=LEFT(MID(@A:A,FIND("q=",@A:A)+2,999),IFERROR(FIND("&",MID(@A:A,FIND("q=",@A:A)+2,999))-1,999))
```

Replace `@A:A` with the reference to the URL cell.

This won't work if there's another `q=` earlier in the URL - if that's a concern it'd be possible to look for a `?q=` or `&q=` instead of for `q=`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks super useful - I also made some further amendments for my usecase if it helps anyone else where $CJ2 is the URL and DH$1 is the URL param to lookup
`=IFERROR(LEFT(MID($CJ2,FIND(DH$1,$CJ2)+LEN(DH$1),999),IFERROR(FIND("&",MID($CJ2,FIND(DH$1,$CJ2)+LEN(DH$1),999))-1,999)), "")`